# Incrementing app version using codemagic in flutter

Tags: flutter, continuous-integration, versioning, codemagic

[image]

I don't understand what does codemagic team mean on this screenshot. Why should I add 100 to build number? Or this is just an example? And when should I update 1.0.0 to 1.0.1 or 1.1.0 to 1.2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just an example demonstration how to add greater numbers. Often necessary when you have already built many times locally and are switching to automatic - otherwise your publishing will fail. If you do not have any releases yet, then just using $BUILD_NUMBER is sufficient.

I think updating the build version is up to the developer though - and there are no strict rules how to do it - just move upwards with it.

https://rollout.io/blog/best-practices-when-versioning-a-release/